# What is this "wyverin" Host for MySQL root User?

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL installation at Ubuntu server, it happens to have a few "default" users, like "debian-sys-maint@localhost", "root@127.0.0.1", etc.

I am seeing a "root@wyverin" user in my installation. I've never seen it before, and I don't know from where it appeared. I want to delete it, but I'd like to know if I can safely proceed.

Does anybody know about it? I tried a Google search, but found nothing useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your host name `wyverin`?

Comment: No, it is not. BTW, this server name is "jbruni".

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a host on your network with the name "wyverin", then I would suggest deleting the user account and then securing your mysql installation. As it sounds like you might have some sql injection going on.

It means someone granted permission explicitly to the user `'root'@'wyverin'` at some point.  By no means is this a default entry.